Can I put the same button onto 2 different tabs in a JTabbedPane
I have a JTabbedPane in a Swing application where there is common functionality between the two tabs. Tab 1 is for one thing and tab 2 is for a second thing. Both things have unique actions as well as a couple buttons that act the same in each.
Clearly, I can duplicate the buttons I add to thing 1 to put into thing 2 and have them execute the same actions, but I would like to reuse the buttons so I don't have to keep them in sync. (I actually have many more than 2 in my real application).
Here is the code I distilled down to a somewhat reasonable size. It compiles and runs on its own. Note that the Thing2 tab has all the components I want but the Thing1 tab only has the Thing1 unique components.
Just before posting I wondered if it is the GroupLayout that's the problem. I will try to use BoxLayout to see if the problem persists.
 
public class LowLevelMinimal extends JPanel {

// Variables declaration
public JButton jButton_Thing2;
public JButton jButton_Thing1;
public JButton jButton_Both2;
public JButton jButton_Both1;
private JLabel jLabel_Both2;
private JLabel jLabel_Both1;
private JLabel jLabel_Thing1;
public JTextField jTextField_Thing2;
public JTextField jTextField_Thing1;
public JTextField jTextField_Both2;
public JTextField jTextField_Both1;
private JPanel panel_Thing1;
private JPanel panel_Thing2;
private JTabbedPane jTabbedPaneChipType;

public LowLevelMinimal()
{
    super();
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents()
{
    jLabel_Thing1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
    jTextField_Thing1 = new JTextField("ONE");
    jButton_Thing1 = new JButton("Thing1 Go");
    jTextField_Thing2 = new JTextField("TWO");
    jButton_Thing2 = new JButton("Thing2 Go");
    jLabel_Both1 = new JLabel("Turn On");
    jLabel_Both2 = new JLabel("Turn Off");
    jTextField_Both1 = new JTextField();
    jTextField_Both2 = new JTextField();
    jButton_Both1 = new JButton("First Both");
    jButton_Both2 = new JButton("Second Both");
    jTextField_Both1.setText("1");
    jTextField_Both2.setText("2");

    panel_Thing1 = new JPanel();
    panel_Thing2 = new JPanel();
    jTabbedPaneChipType = new JTabbedPane();
    jTabbedPaneChipType.addTab("Thing1", panel_Thing1);
    jTabbedPaneChipType.addTab("Thing2", panel_Thing2);

    GroupLayout layoutThing1 = new GroupLayout(panel_Thing1);
    panel_Thing1.setLayout(layoutThing1);
    layoutThing1.setHorizontalGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layoutThing1.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layoutThing1.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel_Thing1, GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                    .addGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layoutThing1.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                            .addGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jTextField_Thing1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                            .addGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jButton_Thing1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addGroup(layoutThing1.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel_Both1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jTextField_Both1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton_Both1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(layoutThing1.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel_Both2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jTextField_Both2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton_Both2, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    ).addContainerGap()
    ))));

    layoutThing1.setVerticalGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layoutThing1.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel_Both1, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jTextField_Both1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton_Both1))
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel_Both2)
                .addComponent(jTextField_Both2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton_Both2))
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layoutThing1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel_Thing1)
                .addComponent(jTextField_Thing1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton_Thing1))
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addContainerGap()
    ));

    GroupLayout layoutThing2 = new GroupLayout(panel_Thing2);
    panel_Thing2.setLayout(layoutThing2);

    layoutThing2.setHorizontalGroup(layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(
            layoutThing2.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(
                layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                    layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addGroup(
                        layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(
                            layoutThing2.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                            .addGroup(layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jTextField_Thing2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                            .addGroup(layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jButton_Thing2, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        )
                        .addGroup(
                            layoutThing2.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel_Both1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jTextField_Both1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton_Both1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        )
                        .addGroup(layoutThing2.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel_Both2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jTextField_Both2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton_Both2, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        )))
            ).addContainerGap()
        ));

    layoutThing2.setVerticalGroup(layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layoutThing2.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel_Both1, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jTextField_Both1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton_Both1))
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel_Both2)
                .addComponent(jTextField_Both2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton_Both2))
            .addGroup(layoutThing2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField_Thing2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton_Thing2))
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addContainerGap()
    ));
    this.add(jTabbedPaneChipType);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    LowLevelMinimal llm = new LowLevelMinimal();
    frame.getContentPane().add(llm);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}

Reuse the Action that the button uses, as in AbstractAction. If you add the same Action to two JButtons, they will behave exactly the same. An Action is like an ActionListener on steroids.

I was thinking also to use an Action here instead of the same button.  Buttons have fields and properties related to their position on the screen, it might "work" for this case but seems a very bad habit to reuse components on different panels.  Actions are the correct way to do this, to make two components "the same."  At least if I understand the use case.

I understand actions and I can create multiple buttons that execute the same action (as I said in paragraph 2 above). I've done that many times. Apparently, the answer to my question is that you can't do what I want (without some ridiculous complex code). This was answered in the linked question (which I did not find when I searched).
